# how to extract specific row from db2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to fetch specific row from DB2.

```
select istore,row_num() over() from store where row_num()=2;
```

so here i need to fetch 2nd row from store table but above query is not fetching any data.please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch it in a outer query like

```
select * from
(
select istore, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY some_column ORDER BY some_column) AS rn 
from store 
) tab
where rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what exactly your problem is, but there are two errors in your statement:

1. The window function is named `row_number()` not, `row_num()`
2. You can't use a window function in the where clause.

Using `row_number()` without any `order by` doesn't make sense, because you wind up with a random ordering.

```
select *
from (
   select istore,
          row_number() over (order by something) as rn
   from store
) t
where rn = 2;
```

Replace `something` with a column name that defines the order of your rows. Without any ordering there is no such thing as "the second row".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way, without using the ROW_NUMBER() function.
(This only works, if you order by a column which is unique in its values)

```
select *
from (
   select *
   from store
   order by something asc
   fetch first 2 rows only
) 
order by something desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```